# Sugar daddy prepaid card scam

Tags: scams, cryptocurrency, sugar-daddy, gift-card

For a couple of weeks, I have been talking to a sugar daddy. He sent me a “prepaid” card, which is now activated, and he requested that I withdraw a large amount and deposit into his Bitcoin wallet. Is this some sort of scam?

Answer (score 66):

Yes it is. You might want to check out some of the other questions on this site tagged [scams](/questions/tagged/scams) or [sugar-daddy](/questions/tagged/sugar-daddy). Cut off contact with this person and do not have anything further to do with them.

Almost certainly the prepaid card was not his own money but stolen from another victim. He is trying to use you to launder the money.

Comment: And don’t use the card!

Comment: The OP is **already in serious legal trouble** since she has **accepted stolen property**.  If by bad luck this particular ring is investigated, she'll be called in.  She should go to the police straight away, give them the card, and perhaps hire a lawyer also.  At the very least she should go to community legal advice and get advice - today.

Comment: OP is not in serious legal trouble. She was given a gift that she had know idea was stolen or illicit. The police are not going to sweep up one individual.

Comment: I'd add in a bit about reporting this to the police or other appropriate authorities, which includes giving them the card. If it somehow turns out this isn't a scam, the card should be returned and they can safely use it. If this is the scam it likely is, it's one more way to track the person(s) putting it on and helping to stop them from scamming other people.

Comment: At this point in time, we should probably have a warning about "Sugar Daddies" in the header of this site. It's always a scam, every time. Nobody is sending you thousands of dollars for some nude pics... you aren't that special nor good looking, and you can get pics for free on the internet. Use your head people.

Comment: @SnakeDoc I think it's more likely that any time that a "Sugar Daddy" does something that'd provoke someone into asking a Question on here that it's a scam. There's some really thirsty simps out there. Just look at how angry the girls on OnlyFans were after the site implemented a maximum payment amount after one girl scammed thousands of guys hundreds of dollars each, and then the site had to handle lots of them doing credit card chargebacks over it.

Comment: This is money muling, not money laundering.

Comment: @Fattie In the UK at least, that is incorrect. As with many crimes, the actus reus (the act) alone is not sufficient, you also need mens rea (intention or recklessness). See Theft Act 1968 section 22(1): "A person handles stolen goods if (otherwise than in the course of the stealing) **knowing or believing them to be stolen goods** he dishonestly receives the goods" (emphasis added). The burden of proof would be on the prosecution to prove beyond reasonable doubt that OP knew or believed the card to be stolen at the time they were given it.

Comment: @SnakeDoc check out the tag wiki, its not front and center but it is the best place I know of in SE to share common warnings and info. https://money.stackexchange.com/tags/sugar-daddy/info

Comment: @JBentley yet the court might conclude that no reasonable person could honestly believe that "working at home paying money from one account to other" and getting big pay for that was a legitimate job. Even though (sadly) we see many people fall for it. I don't think it's as bad as showed by Fattie, but could face some trouble. Even just needing to pay back the amount received may be problematic if it was already spent.

Comment: @Ángel (1) in a theft case heard in the crown court, it is the jury which are finders of fact, not the court (albeit theft is an either way offence so it could be tried by magistrates). (2) there is also the requirement that "he **dishonestly** receives the goods". Dishonesty is defined in common law as "conduct that is deceitful or not honest". Remember the burden of proof is on the prosecution and the standard is beyond reasonable doubt. Given that OP is on here questioning whether it is a scam, the prosecution is going to have a very hard time proving that OP acted with dishonesty.

Comment: @Freiheit That is not good advice. You have no idea how money was loaded on that card. If a stolen credit card or forged check was used to put money on the card then it will be easily traced back to OP who will be in trouble even if she did not know.

Answer (score 39):

### HUGE scam.  Gigantic scam.

Bitcoin is a money transaction that is irreversible.  Once sent, it can't be reversed, EVER.  Anytime person X sends you money, and then wants money *back* via an *irreversible* transaction -- *that's always [a scam](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/blog/2020/03/whats-money-mule-scam)*.

Some other irreversible methods are Western Union and Zelle. But there are still others.

The money they send *you* is sent via a reversible method.  See how that works? After you send money in a way you can't undo, *they undo their original payment to you*.

And leave you holding the bag.

(and yes, quite often *that* money was stolen from another victim, possibly a victim of something else like hacking or identity theft).  These crime rings are actually fairly complex and have teams of people working different specialties.

### It hurts because you think they care

It is, after all, a *[confidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_trick)* game: the objective is to tangle you up in emotions so you'll do crazy things with money.  So it can be very hurtful to discover (and admit) they only want you as a scam victim.

If you really, really, really want to believe this is the real deal, then see how they react to alternate ways of paying them, which would break their scam.  **See how they react to the proposal**.  (don't actually do any of this; just propose it).

- Ask for their PayPal **email address** (do not under any circumstances let them send you a link; do not click any link!!) and tell them that you'll make a PayPal merchandise payment. (often reversible due to PayPal Buyer Protection.)
- Offer to send their own gift card back to them.

If they work hard to convince you not to, that's the sure sign of a scammer.

Again don't actually *do* those things; if you did, they'd have you send the money to yet another scam victim, and you'd just be continuing the scam.

It also tends to help in these cases to absolutely insist on video chat for all communications.  That will usually make scammers go away, because they don't have any humans in the crime syndicate who look like the pictures they sent.

You can also use Google "reverse image search" to find the source of those pictures. Many scammers just grab handsome photos off the Internet.

Comment: I was with you up until the last part. Don't use PayPal. https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/130084/paid-a-scammer-money-via-paypal-what-can-i-do Just don't change money for people over "change for a 20". If you feel the urgent need to do something, use Google for 30 seconds and send the person a link to a service that will convert whatever type of currency they have ("buy bitcoin with prepaid card" returns 2.4 MILLION results).

Comment: @user3067860 In that case the victim disregarded my "don't send as gift" advice.  If it had been sent as payment for merchandise, PayPal would have cheerfully reversed it under Buyer Protection 'item not as described'.  But I'll clarify I only mean it as a scammer test, not to actually send the money.

Comment: Zelle can be reversible. And I don't see how gift cards are reversible.

Comment: @Acccumulation Zelle sternly warns people not to send money to anyone they don't trust, and they back up the "not reversible" narrative with every single thing they say.  Maybe they're lying to discourage casual reversals, but I don't want to put it to the test. Gift card value can be canceled by the issuer.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how a prepaid card can be reversible? If OP goes to an ATM and uses the card to withdraw cash, how could that be reversed?

Comment: @Robert The scammer can have the victim go online and confirm the card has value, after that the scammer (or other victim) removes the value, then victim goes to cash out card, no funds.

Comment: @Robert - it isn't usual to purchase bitcoin with cash, so drawing the money (which is likely a substantial amount) wouldn't be a useful step in actually completing the instructions. You'd use the card online from a bitcoin vendor -- and any reputable bitcoin vendor will need to see proof of id, so when the inevitable chargeback lands, they can threaten to sue you if you don't pay up via other means.

Answer (score 2):

I must reply to Harper.

Judging from the question, facts mentioned in the answer are not necessarily happening that way. Indeed, that's a scam.

> he sent me a “prepaid” card which is now activated

Whose card is that? It shouldn't be on your name. A sugar daddy normally sends *his own* card to support the OP, who whithdraws money from the card for their own use at the amounts agreed with the daddy. The daddy may also want to use a prepaid card so that the OP never drains the SD's account.

But if you sent your ID to the SD previously, my answer must stop here. That fact is not disclosed in the question, so I assume not.

### Bitcoin transfers are irreversible, bank transfers are reversible

### These transfers come from scams/laundering

The above are facts.

Now, what happens is that the transfers made to the prepaid card (whether it has an IBAN associated or not) **can** be reversed, and the person holding the card's name **can** be prosecuted for refund. I don't know the correct English word, but with *prosecuted* I don't (yet) mean criminal proceedings, but at least a plethora of creditors *chasing* the card holder for life until debt is repaid. And debt can be considerable.

So, assuming the SD sent his own card, he is accountable for the debt that eventually reaches the card.

Of course, it is likely that the SD, being part of a crime group, is not using his real ID to obtain a payment card. And that is another part of the story.

### Money laundering is a crime

By actively transferring Bitcoins to your SD, you are surely helping a criminal. For now, I want to assume that only the SD has your contact details and knows who you are or who you claim to be.

Withdrawing money from a card with the purpose of sending Bitcoins is being a *collateral* in crime, and you could be prosecuted for that.

While your name may not be on the card, your face can be recorded by ATM security cameras, so the cops may come to you one day or another. Even if they won't find you (or the amounts laundered are not big enough to justify expensive investigations), you are still helping crime and we must warn you about it. As you are responsible for your own choices.

### Blackmail spiral

There is also another risk. After you enter in this loop, the SD may reveal that you are helping criminals launder money. Leveraging your weakness, the SD may turn you into collateral for additional crime, and subjugate you to his will. Threatening to sue you, to tell your name to the cops, for example.

Because, as we are telling you, withdrawing someone else's money to send Bitcoins is source for money laundering.

### The difference

IMO the difference with Harper's answer lies in this statement

> After you send money in a way you can't undo, they undo their original payment to you. And leave you holding the bag.

If the card is not under the OP's name, the OP won't suffer the reverse charge and the payment won't be undone on the OP. I don't think *that* is the point. If I manage to obtain a card under someone's name and put that card into deep red balance, the bank will go find the person whose name is on the card. Who will be held repsonsible until [contrary is proven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burden_of_proof_(law)).

Note that I said "if I manage to obtain (a card under someone's name)" and I never hypothesized how do I.

Comment: Who said the prepaid card has a name on it?

Answer (score 2):

A real sugar daddy gives you money for your services. You never give money to your sugar daddy, not in any form. As soon as you are asked to give money to your sugar daddy, we don't even have to look at what exactly is happening, we know it is a scam. Because it violates the rules: Sugar daddy pays, you take. You don't pay.

(And in your case what happens will be that the prepaid card is dodgy in some way, so if you get a prepaid card with $1,000 today and send off $500 worth of bitcoin, then next month your bank will ask you to pay the $1,000 back, and there is nothing you can do about that, and you are $500 out of pocket).