# Sugar daddy requested that I verify my bitcoin on Cash App — is it a scam?

Tags: scams, cryptocurrency, sugar-daddy

A "sugar daddy" requested that I send him my [Cash App](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cash_App) tag (username) so that he could put me on his payroll. He told me that I would then need to verify my bitcoin and pay a small fee of $70 so that the payment roll verification can be completed and that it is not a Cash App clearance.

I am very skeptical about this. I asked him why I needed bitcoin if I do not plan on using it, and he replied "[because] you are gonna use it to complete your verification" and then told me how I need to add the $70 to my account and then purchase bitcoin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sugar daddy prepaid card scam](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/130531/sugar-daddy-prepaid-card-scam)

Comment: All you need are the words "sugar daddy".  Yes, it's a scam.

Comment: "Sugar daddy" can mean one of two things. (1) it's a euphemism for prostitution, or (2) it's a scam.  If you're not doing (1), it will be (2).

Answer (score 16):

Anyone who promises to pay you money but first insists that you send money someplace they direct is trying to scam you. Now that you know this person is a scammer, it is vital that your permanently cut off all contact with them. Don't give them more chances to scam you.